# Regex lookbehind

Tags: regex

Preciso escrever um regex para parsear um trecho de um campo da mensagem swift, para isso estou utilizando o *lookbehind*.

No exemplo abaixo tenho as duas strings que preciso das 12 posições do bic.
Na primeira string seria `TESTBIC34XXX`
Na segunda string `YOURBANKXJKL`

O problema é que os campos entre `O564` e `TESTBIC34XXX` são opcionais

```
String1 = "2:O5641057130214TESTBIC34XXX26264938281302141757N"
String2 = "2:I101YOURBANKXJKLU3003"
```

Tentei utilizar o lookbehind variando os dígitos de 3 a 13, porque os 3 dígitos após o "I" ou "O" são obrigatórios.
Não resolveu porque sempre a regex vai encontrar os 3 primeiros dígitos e vai parar.

```
Pattern = (?<=[IO]\d{3,13})\w{12}
```

Já tentei diversas abordagens condicionais sem sucesso.
Alguém tem alguma sugestão ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Regex`s de javascript não têm suporte para *lookbehind*. Existe alguma razão pela qual você não pode dizer `/[IO]\d{3,13}(\w{12})/.exec(String1)[1]`?  Afinal de contas, uma regex com *lookbehind* é semanticamente equivalente a uma com um grupo de captura prefixado com o *lookbehind*...

EDIT: .NET tem *lookbehind*, mas aparentemente ele não é [guloso](http://aurelio.net/regex/guia/quantificadores-gulosos.html). Você pode, em último caso, usar o mesmo padrão do javascript acima e dizer `Regex.Match(@"[IO]\d{3,13}(\w{12})", String1).Groups[1].Value` e `Regex.Match(@"[IO]\d{3,13}(\w{12})", String2).Groups[1].Value` para obter o código que você deseja em ambos os exemplos.

Comment: Opa tudo bem. Não estou realizando o match pelo JS. É Java e .Net. Estou utilizando o lookbehind para não receber o prefix, só quero mesmo o \w{12}

Comment: Entendi. boa. Obrigado pela resposta, solucionou o problema.

Answer (score 3):

#### Regras (pelo que compreendi)

- Deve começar com I ou O.
- `[IO]` deve ser seguido de no mínimo 3 dígitos.
- Apos os dígitos e se iniciar texto deve capturar os próximos 12 caracteres.

#### REGEX Padrão

`[IO]\d{3,}(\w{12})` Veja no [REGEX101](https://regex101.com/r/IE7X62/1)

#### Problema

Você não quer capturar o que vem antes, para isso esta usando o *lookbehind*. O problema dele é que [ele não aceita quantificadores](https://regex101.com/r/IE7X62/2), ou seja [ele quer que você seja especifico](https://regex101.com/r/IE7X62/3) em relação ao que vem antes.

Então seu problema esta ai, você não poderia usar o *lookbehind*, já que você mesmo disse:

> O problema é que os campos entre O564 e TESTBIC34XXX [são opcionais](https://regex101.com/r/IE7X62/4)

O *lookbehind* seria para garantir que uma determinada sentença ocorra antes da captura, [para garantir uma especificidade](https://regex101.com/r/EZpZl3/1).

#### Resolução

Você pode ate conseguir montar alguma REGEX para capturar só o que deseja, mas em vez de perder todo esse tempo, sugiro simplesmente manter a REGEX padrão e trabalhar com o grupo de captura. Utilizando o `Match[1]`.

#### Nota

- Todos os links do **Problema**, mostram porque não usar *lookbehind* (no seu caso).

Comment: Guilherme, obrigado pela resposta completa, ajudou muito para esclarecer bem o conceito do lookbehind, muito boa referência, acabei marcando a resposta do Wtrmute por ele ter respondido antes. Mas de qualquer forma obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: @user1987610 Tranquilo, que bom que ajudou :D